Is there a way to connect to a WFS shared folder with .net8.0?
I'm trying to programmatically copy a file from one folder to a shared folder on another computer. I've figured out how to get the file, but I'm stuck on connecting to the shared folder.
Any guidance on the best method to connect and copy the file to the shared folder would be greatly appreciated.
Im using .net8.0 and azure functions
I've attempted using Windows impersonation, but wasn't successful. I also considered HttpClient, but I'm unsure about the proper approach for this scenario.
